# How sites can detect --remote-debugging-port chrome switch

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools, bots

I have an issue with some sites. When I start a regular chrome, all goes ok. But when I add --remote-debugging-port="%PORT%" command line switch, some site can detect this and consider that I am a bot. I'm really need to undarstand how sites (using js I guess) can detect the switch or how to bypass this tests. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have already figured out the problem.

When chrome started with

> --remote-debugging-port="%PORT%"

switch, the

> navigator.webdriver

property is set to *true*. But normally it is *undefined*

Comment: Have in mind that you can (and should) accept your own answer, so others will easily see the mark and know the solution.

Comment: @SimfikDuke so you put `navigator.webdriver` to `true`? Wouldn't that tell the websites you are using automation since that's what webdriver is used for?

Comment: @zen you can always override the value of `navigator.webdriver` by overriding it's prototype. `Object.defineProperty(Navigator.prototype, "webdriver", {value: undefined});`